# adding CSS styling to the <xsl:element name="standard_element_name">

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

As per SO standards, I have researched this question in Google and Yahoo, and on W3Schools and other forums for hours before posting here.
All answers I have found so far are geared towards specialized XML languages and other application that are going to read the XML file.
I am not doing this, nor am I writing any other type of code (such as C++, Java, C#, etc; nor am I wanting to use JavaScript).

The small local site I am creating is using only files in HTML, XML, and XSL, and a hand full of image files stored as .jpg and png. There is nothing else.

My little site is running on a local PC based Windows 10 computer with IIS enabled. The site works and other computers can view it in the common web browsers (such as FireFox and Chrome) through the LAN.

The only issue is my coding.

My project is to create a very basic, static site with simple HTML to the output, using nothing but XML and XSLT.

I have an XSL file which defines all of the standard HTML tags in templates [such as (p) (div) (table) (tr) (th) (td), etc] I also have many custom tags, which is why I want to use XML.)

I have reached a point where I want to use the (xsl:element name=" "). For example, I want to define a typical HTML (p style="color:yellow;"), using the (xsl:element name="p").

Here is a small sample of xsl I already have:

```
<xsl:element name="p">
    <xsl:value-of select="p" />
</xsl:element>
```

This works, and a very plain (p) tag is created in the output and all the text is displayed. But, it has no styling. In the browser output it looks like this

```
<p>
     A paragraph of text in here.
</p>
```

Having explained the above, my question is (hoping to be very clear), how to do I use the (xsl: element name="p") as shown above to add style attributes to it so my HTML output looks something like this:

```
<p style="background-color:yellow; font-size: 16pt;">
   A paragraph of text in here, which is now black on a yellow background and a 16 point font.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have answered my own question, and have included my complete, actual XSLT and some of my XML file for others that may be struggling with this. The short answer is the (xsl:attribute name="style") that is directly below the (xsl:element name="div").

I have included the complete code, which creates a (div) in the output on the left side that remains in a fixed position (meaning it does not scroll). This is a space for a list of links to other chapters used as a menu. The short piece of code beginning with the (xsl:element name="div") and ending with the closing tag (/xsl:element) creates that area, and the (for-each) block reads all the (list-text) and (url) tags [children of the (side_menu_div) tag, then creates a list of links in the (div) area on the side.

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


        <xsl:template match="ROOT">

            <html>
                <head>
                    <xsl:element name="title">
                        <xsl:value-of select="title" />
                    </xsl:element>
                </head>

                <body style="background-color:#fffc99;">
                        <xsl:element name="div">
                            <xsl:attribute name="style">width: 10%; height: 100%; position: fixed; padding-right: 1em; background: white</xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:for-each select="/ROOT/side_menu_div/link-text">
                                <xsl:variable name="index" select="position()" />
                                <a href="{/ROOT/side_menu_div/url[$index]}">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                </a>
                                <br/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:element>  
                </body>

            </html>

        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The actual XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/style-sheets/master.xsl"?>

    <ROOT>

    <title>Player's Core Rulebook</title>



    <side_menu_div>
        <link-text>Home Menu</link-text>
            <url>/methasia_index.html</url>
            <br></br>
        <link-text>Preamble</link-text>
           <url>/rulebooks/_players_core_rulebook/00-Preamble/Preamble.xml</url>
        <link-text>Chapter 1</link-text>
           <url>/rulebooks/_players_core_rulebook/01-Chapter-01/chapter_1.xml</url>
        <link-text>Chapter 2</link-text> 
           <url>/rulebooks/_players_core_rulebook/02-Chapter-02/chapter_2.xml</url>
        <link-text>Chapter 3</link-text> 
           <url>/rulebooks/_players_core_rulebook/03-Chapter-03/chapter_3.xml</url>
        <link-text>Chapter 4</link-text> 
           <url>/rulebooks/_players_core_rulebook/04-Chapter-04/chapter_4.xml</url>
        <link-text>Chapter 5</link-text> 
           <url>/rulebooks/_players_core_rulebook/05-Chapter-05/chapter_5.xml</url>
        <link-text>Chapter 6</link-text> 
           <url>/rulebooks/_players_core_rulebook/06-Chapter-06/chapter_6.xml</url>
        <link-text>Chapter 7</link-text> 
           <url>/rulebooks/_players_core_rulebook/07-Chapter-07/chapter_7.xml</url>
        <link-text>Chapter 8</link-text>
           <url>/rulebooks/_players_core_rulebook/08-Chapter-08/chapter_8.xml</url>
        <link-text>Chapter 9</link-text> 
           <url>/rulebooks/_players_core_rulebook/09-Chapter-09/chapter_9.xml</url>
        <link-text>Chapter 10</link-text> 
           <url>/rulebooks/_players_core_rulebook/10-Chapter-10/chapter_10.xml</url>
        <link-text>Appendix</link-text> 
           <url>/rulebooks/_players_core_rulebook/11-Appendix/Players_Core_Rulebook_Appendix.xml</url> 
    </side_menu_div>
```

Comment: `<xsl:element name="div"><xsl:attribute..>` works of course, but why not just do `<div style="..">..`?